# nth-of-type, first-child does not work properly

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to give radius property on 1st, 3th, 5th img or div element.
Tried first-child, .image img:nth-of-type(1)  but both of them give the radius to every five elements. Can anyone give me an answer to why this is happening?

```
.image img:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

```
    <div className="container">
        <div className="gallery-container w-2 h-2">
          <div className="gallery-item">
            <div className="image">
              <img src={this.props.photos.room_photos[0].imageUrl} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="gallery-container">
          <div className="gallery-item">
            <div className="image">
              <img src={this.props.photos.room_photos[1].imageUrl} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="gallery-container">
          <div className="gallery-item">
            <div className="image">
              <img src={this.props.photos.room_photos[2].imageUrl} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="gallery-container">
          <div className="gallery-item">
            <div className="image">
              <img src={this.props.photos.room_photos[3].imageUrl} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="gallery-container">
         <div className="gallery-item">
            <div className="image">
              <img src={this.props.photos.room_photos[4].imageUrl} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the selectors wrong, `.image img:first-child` means the `img` which is first child of each `.images` div, that is why it is setting border radius to all images, So instead start from the parent div with class `.container` and find its 1st, 3rd  and 5th child and then add the border to image in those child divs

So try using this:

```
/* Select every other div item starting with first */
.container .gallery-container:nth-child(odd) .image img{
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: you're welcome, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

> Considering you need the `odd` CSS already has a property called 'nth-child()` for these kind of purpose [nth-child()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).
>
> The parameter in your case is `odd` just pass that to the parent class, I see `galary-container` choose `nth-child()` for that class, you're free to use it's successor as well.

```css
.gallery-container:nth-child(odd) img {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery-container w-2 h-2">
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/201/201" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/201/201" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/201/201" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lol.. I see you tried choosing both the answers, however you can choose only one, so you can choose the best one and vote if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
How about the :nth-child(3n+3)?
(3 x 0) + 3 = 3 = 3rd Element
(3 x 1) + 3 = 6 = 6th Element
(3 x 2) + 3 = 9 = 9th Element
etc.

How about the :nth-child(2n+1)?

(2 x 0) + 1 = 1 = 1st Element
(2 x 1) + 1 = 3 = 3rd Element
(2 x 2) + 1 = 5 = 5th Element
etc.

# 3, 6, 9 element
.container .gallery-container:nth-child(3n+3) .image img{
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

# 1, 3, 5 element
.container .gallery-container:nth-child(2n+1) .image img{
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

For your selectors positions.